# UI Routing with a 'root' state does not resolve before child state controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For an application I'm working on in AngularJS I have the following problem:

- Before the application can be launched - I've set 2 resolve functions to load translations from rest / properties from a local file.
- I've added a 2 resolve functions on the 'root' state of the application
- I've defined 'child states' which should inherit the resolve from the 'root state'
- I notice that the custom function controller on a child state is not executed after the resolve functions of the root state

States definitions:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/start');

$stateProvider

    // load dependencies on state
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        template: "<div class='page' ui-view></div>",
        resolve: {      
            // load properties  
            loadProperties: function(properties){
                alert('load properties');
                return properties.initProperties();
            },
            // load labels
            loadLocalization: function(localize, loadProperties){
                alert('load localization');
                return localize.initLocalizedResources();
            }
        }
    })

    // dashboard : general index
    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "partials/dashboard/dashboard.html",
        controller: "dashboardController",            
        resolve:{
            // load workorders
            loadData: function(wkorderService){
                alert('load work orders service data');
                return wkorderService.getData(null, null);
            }
        }
    })

});
```

I've added alerts to check the sequence, and I notice when accessing the `app.dashboard` state through the URL `/dashboard` the order of alerts:

- alert('load properties');
- alert('load work orders service data');
- alert('load localization');

In order of the resolve - the last alert should be executed in the resolve of the root state, and not before the resolve of the child state.

Am I missing something ... 
Thanks in advance for looking into this issue!

Comment: ui-router 0.2.x processes all resolves for the entire transition together.  As you've found, adding a dependency on a parent state's resolve in a child state provides can be used to order the resolve execution.  In ui-router 1.0, we are adding resolve policy which allows you to specify if you want that behavior ("eager policy"), if you want to wait until the state is being entered ("lazy policy"), or if you don't want the resolve to happen until just before it's about to be injected elsewhere ("just-in-time policy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, changing the 'app.dashboard' state to the following fixed my problem :

```
// dashboard : general index
.state('app.dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "partials/dashboard/dashboard.html",
    controller: "dashboardController",            
    resolve:{
        // load workorders
        loadData: function(wkorderService,loadLocalization){
            alert('load work orders service data');
            return wkorderService.getData(null, null);
        }
    }
})
```

I thought the resolve of the 'root' state were automatically invoked before the resolve of the child state. Guess it was not, therefor specifically adding the `loadLocalization` resolve in the loadData method constructor.